# Is Git Smart Enough to Merge After Refactoring

Tags: java, git

### Assume I have a class.

```
package org.my.domain;

public class BestClassEver{}
```

---

### My Workflow

**Through some refactoring, I change this class's package.**

```
package org.another.domain;

public class BestClassEver{}
```

**I commit this to my local repository using git and push it to a remote repository.**

```
git add .
git commit -m "Refactoring"
git push origin master
```

---

### Another Developer's Workflow

**Another developer modifies the class, without pulling my changes.**

```
package org.my.domain;

public class BestClassEver{
    private String something;
}
```

**Then commits and pushes to the remote repository**

```
git add .
git commit -m "Some Changes"
git push origin master
```

---

### Questions

1. Will Git merge the other developer's changes into the class?
2. If not, what happens?
3. Is this workflow something that needs to be coordinated amongst the team?

Comment: I believe whoever pushes 2nd will get an error when they try to push, because it will not be a fast-forward commit. They'll have to pull the latest, rebase or merge their changes in, and then push. In this case, there's a good chance the merge will be automatic, but if not it will be up to that developer to perform the correct merge.

Comment: @grossvogel So your saying I need to push this quickly before anyone else does?  J/K  Actually there would be a benefit of letting everyone know they should check in before I perform the repackaging, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Git won't allow the other developer to push his changes without pulling.

It will throw an error that both refs don't match and therefore his local branch needs to be updated with the remote refs.

That's pretty much all there is to know about that. If there are changes in the remote repository, unless you do a forced push, git won't allow you to push changes if there are changes in the remote.

**EDIT**

Once he pulls, if there are any conflicts in the file, the developer will have to correct any conflicts, commit them and only then he will be able to push.

If there are no conflicts, git will automatically merge those changes and the developer will be able to push after the pull.

**EDIT AGAIN**

I didn't realize that you were moving the file. In any case, running `git status` would give you an idea as to the state of your local repository after a pull. If there was any conflicts, you'd be able to correct them.

**NOTE**

On `git rebase` or `git pull --rebase` are usually used to give you a much cleaner commit history as they will pretty much will apply any local changes on top of any other changes that were pulled.

On the other hand, `git pull` and `git merge` will usually make an extra commit to link the changes on the branches.

For more information take a look at this guide [Git Rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing)

Comment: so what I'm reading into your edit is that Git will recognize that the file has moved and merge their changes into the newly relocated file automatically?

Comment: @KevinBowersox If refactoring tool does not support git and does not do the move/rename using appropriate git command, git will not magically recognize that. So check status before committing, I think you can fix it by hand too.

Comment: I don't believe git will recognize that the file was moved and automatically merge the changes but it will definitely give you an error stating that and you'd probably have to fix it by hand, then commit, then push changes.

Answer (score 1):

It is always good idea to let people work on different parts of program.

Merge or rebase in this case should be fully automatic, but in real world it is always a bit dramatic and sometimes there are some conflicts. Of course, this merge/rebase will be done after server rejects push for beeing non-fast-forward.

Comment: By rebase you meaning changing the location of the file?

Comment: No, I mean `git rebase` or `git pull --rebase` commands. It is like merge, but git removes your local commits first, then applies remote commits and then re-apply your local commits.

Answer (score 0):

When such thing fails, some workarounds include:

1. Just repeating "refactoring" in the other branch prior to merging;
2. Converting the work to patch (`git format-patch`), editing the patch (applying that "refactor" to it) and applying the edited patch (`git am`). It is like manual rebasing.

I think it's better to separate merge-complicating refactoring (one that involves renaming, for example) and usual minor refactoing.

Sometimes for a merge-complicating refactoing a script can be written (such as `find -name '*.c' -exec sed 's/something/anything/g' -i '{}' ';'`). The script be used to repeat the refactoring multiple times in various places when we need it, so avoiding to merge refactored code with non-refactored one.

Answer (score 0):

YES. Git is able to identify those changes. I am working on a project using git on my own fork (forked from origin). In the meantime another developer refactored the codebase on the original fork, which includes changing package structure.

I used the following commands:

- git stash save // this saves all your work onto a personal stash
- git pull // fetches all the latest changes on the primary fork and merges
- git stash apply stash@{0} // or whatever the stash is where you saved your personal work

Now you will have the refactored codebase+your changes. You can now commit without any conflict and the packaging will not be changed.

Just note that in my case I waited for the original fork to be refactored and then I committed my changes, which are only changes to few files and not repackaging.

Also note that if you have added new files, then you might have to edit a few imports to make sure the imports are correct. 
eg. import org.my.domain;
should now be edited to: import org.another.domain;